# Calculate length of curve created by interpolation of polar coordinates

Tags: polar-coordinates, interpolation

Given two points in polar coordinates how to calculate length of the curve created by linear interpolation of angle and distance between those points? [Polar interpolation curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1j4A.png)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to answer my own question, it is possible to create infinite amounts of points on the curve by interpolation. The length of curve is sum of distances between the points.